# Saving Matplotlib Output to Blob Storage on Databricks

Tags: matplotlib, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to write matplotlib figures to the Azure blob storage using the method provided here:
[Saving Matplotlib Output to DBFS on Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57203817/saving-matplotlib-output-to-dbfs-on-databricks/60188964?noredirect=1#comment106459449_60188964).

However, when I replace the path in the code with

```
path = 'wasbs://test@someblob.blob.core.windows.net/'
```

I get this error

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wasbs://test@someblob.blob.core.windows.net/'

I don't understand the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my research, you cannot save Matplotlib output to Azure Blob Storage directly.

**You may follow the below steps to save Matplotlib output to Azure Blob Storage:**

**Step 1:** You need to first save it to the Databrick File System (DBFS) and then copy it to Azure Blob storage.

Saving Matplotlib output to Databricks File System (DBFS): We are using the below command to save the output to DBFS: `plt.savefig('/dbfs/myfolder/Graph1.png')`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruits':['apple','banana'], 'count': [1,2]})
plt.close()
df.set_index('fruits',inplace = True)
df.plot.bar()
plt.savefig('/dbfs/myfolder/Graph1.png')
```

[image]

**Step 2:** Copy the file from Databricks File System to Azure Blob Storage.

There are two methods to copy file from DBFS to Azure Blob Stroage.

**Method 1: Access Azure Blob storage directly**

Access Azure Blob Storage directly by setting "Spark.conf.set" and copy file from DBFS to Blob Storage.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.< Blob Storage Name>.blob.core.windows.net", "<Azure Blob Storage Key>")
```

Use dbutils.fs.cp to copy file from DBFS to Azure Blob Storage:

```
dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/myfolder/Graph1.png', 'wasbs://<Container>@<Storage Name>.blob.core.windows.net/Azure')
```

[image]

**Method 2: Mount Azure Blob storage containers to DBFS**

You can mount a Blob storage container or a folder inside a container to Databricks File System (DBFS). The mount is a pointer to a Blob storage container, so the data is never synced locally.

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://sampledata@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/Azure",
  mount_point = "/mnt/chepra",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.sampledata.chepra.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "azurestorage", key = "azurestoragekey")})
```

Use dbutils.fs.cp copy the file to Azure Blob Storage Container:

dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/myfolder/Graph1.png', '/dbfs/mnt/chepra')

[image]

By following Method1 or Method2 you can successfully save the output to Azure Blob Storage.

[image]

For more details, refer "[Databricks - Azure Blob Storage](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can write with .savefig() directly to Azure blob storage- you just need to mount the blob container before.

The following works for me, where I had mounted the blob container as /mnt/mydatalakemount

```
plt.savefig('/dbfs/mnt/mydatalakemount/plt.png')
```

or

```
fig.savefig('/dbfs/mnt/mydatalakemount/fig.png')
```

Documentation on mounting blob container is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#--mount-an-azure-blob-storage-container).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I also came up with so far. In order to reload the image from blob and display it as png in a databricks notebook again I use the following code:

```
blob_path = ...
dbfs_path = ...
dbutils.fs.cp( blob_path, dbfs_path ) 

with open( dbfs_path, "rb" ) as f:
  im = BytesIO( f.read() )

img = mpimg.imread( im ) 
imgplot = plt.imshow( img )
display( imgplot.figure )
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't succeed using `dbutils`, which cannot be correctly created.
But I did succeed by mounting the file-shares to a Linux path, like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-mount-files-storage-linux